# Does PDO demand parameters in all SELECT WHERE queries?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm doing the most basic of queries ...

```
SELECT `id` FROM `members` WHERE `group` = 'admin';
```

Running the above query generates `Error: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`.

There's no need for prepared statements because there are no variables, therefore no possibility of injection.

Is this just the nature of PDO, that **any** query containing `WHERE` **must** be bound?

Here's my actual query:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `members` WHERE `group` = 'admin';"
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) { ... }
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Can you post the rest of your code that you are using?

Comment: This should actually be no problem, how are you executing the query or are you accidentally binding something?

Comment: We need the PHP portion of the code to answer this, just the SQL isn't enough.

Comment: Highly optimistic code. Where is the error handling? What if `false` is returned?

Comment: @ZombieHunter removed for simplifying the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is generated when you pass an array to execute that has a different amount of elements than the amount of question marks you have in your query. Zero parameters is possible, but you will also have to pass an empty array.

Comment: Are you sure??
The PDO manual ... http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php ... seems to say otherwise. Am I misreading it?

Comment: @neokio Yes, I am sure. And I think you are misreading it, what part of the manual are you referring to? (Also, the query method does not support binding arguments, that's prepare and execute)

Comment: @neokio: The PHP documentation really needs to be improved, only one parameter is documented. But as you can see you can call query() by passing only the statement, there is no need to pass an empty array.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear with my question! I've added the PHP query above...